# Uninitialized Variable after deleting hyrax work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rollback

I'm working on a hyrax project, after creating a work type with rails with the following command

```
 $ bin/rails generate hyrax:work GenericWork
```

I try to delete the work type with the following commands

```
$ bin/rails destroy hyrax:work GenericWork    
$ rake db:rollback
```

but I keep getting the error

```
Routing error:
Uninitialized constant GenericWork
```

after I delete it with the commands above.

Why is it ?

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://github.com/samvera/hyrax/wiki/Hyrax-Management-Guide#removing-a-work-type), after removing a work type (with `rails destroy hyrax:work GenericWork`) you have to remove the line that registers a work from `config/initializers/hyrax.rb`.

Have you tried that?

Also, can you please search your code for `GenericWork`? `Routing error` suggests it might be used in `routes.rb` file

Comment: `config/initializers/hyrax.rb` is modified already by the command itself, I repeated the action 3 more times and it magically worked ...

Comment: That's strange, because the documentation says something different. Anyway, I am glad that you solved that.